# Saving listview simple_list_item_multiple_choice checkbox state using an Array Adapter

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I am new to programming for Android devices. I am trying to figure out how to save the checkboxes in my listview generated by using the simple_list_item_multiple_choice and Array Adapter.  I would like to be able to save the state of the checkboxes so that when an user hits the back button to go to another checklist they can come back to this checklist and pickup where they left.

Please, please, please help!!  Code and/or explanation would be ideal.

Code:

```
public class BeachBabyStuff extends Activity  {
    String[] beachstuffbaby = new String[]{                                                                
                        "Beach Blanket or Mat",                                             
            "Beach Towels",                                                                      
            "Beach Umbrella",                                                                  
            "Beach Chair",                                                                        
            "Books / Magazines",                                                              
            "Radio",                                                                      
            "Pen / Paper",                                                              
            "Tablet"};                                                                    


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);


        // Getting the reference to the listview object of the layout
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        // The checkbox for the each item is specified by the layout android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, beachstuffbaby);


        // Setting adapter to the listview
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Manage the onItemClick method
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            private View view;

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> ListView, View view, int position, long id) {
                         CheckedTextView textView = (CheckedTextView)view;
                         textView.setChecked(!textView.isChecked());

                         this.view = view;

                                    }

        });
```

Comment: What is current behavior.. AFAIK the states should not change after returning from another activity..

Answer (score 0):

Add a boolean array to your activty that maintains the checks.

```
boolean checked[] = new boolean[beachstuffbaby.length];
```

Set all checked position into this array. Make a comma separated item string from this array and put into `SharedPreferences`.

Restore the states by reading this array from preferences and splitting the string on a comma.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and post my results.  Hopefully this will help someone else too.

Comment: Do I need to add a custom adapter?